Can't receive data via BLE on Android 14
I have created Jetpack compose Android application which connects to a BLE device. BLE device updates its state and sends data to the app. Previously I have used Android 11 device and now I have updated my device to one that has Android 14.
I'm facing problem when trying to send data to app with Android 14. I'm using Nordic Semiconductors Android BLE library v2.9.0. On Android end, I receive characteristic changes like this:
private val dataReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val action = intent!!.action
            Log.i(tag, "This is the action $action")
            try {
                when (action) {
                    bluetoothManager.actionConnected -> {

                    }
                    bluetoothManager.actionDisconnected -> {

                    }
                    bluetoothManager.actionDataAvailable -> {

                    }
                    bluetoothManager.actionInfoAvailable -> {

                    }
                    bluetoothManager.actionError -> {
                       
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(tag, "onReceive ${e.stackTraceToString()}")
            }


When using exactly same code (excluding BLE permissions) with Android 11, I receive data normally and in the Log I get "This is the action ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE" as expected. With Android 14 I get status updates e.g. "This is the action CONNECTED" and "This is the action DISCONNECTED" but for some reason it doesn't register "This is the action ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE". When changing back to phone with Android 11 everything works as expected. I have also verified that code works with Android 12. Problems occurs now only with Android 14.
What might cause this? Are there some sort of security things that I need to take into account etc.?

Ensure you're already defined about permissions bluetooth correctly. For example in manifest you can see in the code below.
// Required permissions in AndroidManifest.xml
/*
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
*/


private val dataReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context == null || intent == null) return
        
        val action = intent.action ?: return
        Log.i(tag, "This is the action $action")
        
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
                // Check runtime permissions for Android 14+
                if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) 
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e(tag, "Missing BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission")
                    return
                }
            }
            
            when (action) {
                bluetoothManager.actionConnected -> {
                    handleConnected()
                }
                bluetoothManager.actionDisconnected -> {
                    handleDisconnected()
                }
                bluetoothManager.actionDataAvailable -> {
                    handleDataAvailable(intent)
                }
                bluetoothManager.actionInfoAvailable -> {
                    handleInfoAvailable(intent)
                }
                bluetoothManager.actionError -> {
                    handleError(intent)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(tag, "onReceive ${e.stackTraceToString()}")
        }
    }
}

// Register receiver with explicit intent filters
private fun registerReceiver() {
    val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(bluetoothManager.actionConnected)
        addAction(bluetoothManager.actionDisconnected)
        addAction(bluetoothManager.actionDataAvailable)
        addAction(bluetoothManager.actionInfoAvailable)
        addAction(bluetoothManager.actionError)
    }
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        context.registerReceiver(dataReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
    } else {
        context.registerReceiver(dataReceiver, filter)
    }
}

// Don't forget to unregister
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    try {
        context.unregisterReceiver(dataReceiver)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(tag, "Error unregistering receiver: ${e.message}")
    }
}

And make sure your code is already register the receiver. To handle logic of the bluetooth access permissions. You can see my sample code in the above to help and make you clear about the solutions. :)

Hi, thanks for the reply but I have already taken care of these additions you have put there. Problem is that every other characteristic read callbacks are executed EXCEPT data read in Android 14. I'm able to register bluetoothManager.actionConnected,  bluetoothManager.actionDisconnected , bluetoothManager.actionInfoAvailable and bluetoothManager.actionError.

It seems that the problem was the MTU size negotiation. For some reason MTU size is always set to 517 in Android 14 even though my peripheral can handle max 247.
